# Клонировать блок и отправить методом пост

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, нужно клонировать блок и отправить, вообщем делаю так:

```
$.ajax({
    ...,
    data: ...+'&summ='+ $(".block").clone(true),
    ....
```

получаю [object Object], как можно еще коопировать и присвоить отправить?

Comment: Ну, стоит начать с того, что это:

      $(".block")

возвращает массив. Если элемент один, возвращает массив с одним значением.

Comment: хм... перебор массива. Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: Да пытаюсь отправить html строку, что то с clone() не получается, а вот сейчас начал с html(), datatype: "html" делаю, че то капризничает. Спасибо за html()

Comment: все сделал) Спасибо eicto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только это не массив, а объект jquery, который перебирать надо `.each()`, вообще вы пытаетесь что отправить? html? Почему бы не взять `$(".block").html()`?